How to prevent calling loaded unloaded methods of Pages and UCs when user reconnects RDC in WPF C#?
In my WPF app i have so many UCs and controls i want to prevent them loading and unloading after user reconnects rdc
I've done alot of research to solve the issue but nothing is working.
When reconnecting to a remote desktop session this happpens.

Controls being unloaded then reloaded

Controls within DataTemplates being completed re-created
is there a way to prevent loading and unloading of controls


my app is running on .NET framework version 4.6
here is my code
public uc()
{
    uc.Loaded +=somemethod;
}
somemethod(){
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
this.AddChild(tb); // after getting called again it adds another textbox 
}

after reconnect the first breakpoint that gets hit is in the constructor and I don't know how to debug it further because the stack trace only shows [external code] before this.

If you add the controls in the XAML code then this problem wouldn't occur. Is there any reason for adding controls to the layout from code-behind?

the reason is we are using the same UC for header everywhere and just changing the children as per the page changes.

If you could be m ore specific then I could suggest a proper solution. It currently looks like you have a UserControl that hosts dynamic content. This content changes based on the current context. In this case you must define that dynamic content inside a DataTemplate. If could extend your example to show a real use case would be a great help.

When it matters, I use a flag (e.g. bool isInitialized = false;) that gets tested and set in the Loaded event. If the flag is false; the routine runs and sets the flag to true so it bypasses Loaded from then on. Often one "tests" the flag wherever one needs, but only sets the flag in the "parent" Loaded event, since it is the last to fire. The "flagless" "solution" is to keep referencing the parent's "IsLoaded" property; assuming "that" is not being constantly reloaded.

As per @GerrySchmitz's comment, I used a flag to track whether the control is loaded or not, setting it accordingly. However, in my app, some user controls (UCs) have the main window as their direct parent, while others have a page or a frame as their parent. After a lot of thinking and trying different solutions, I finally created a method that effectively prevents the problem. While this isn't a direct solution, it's a trick that helps avoid the issue. Here's the code for it
In mainwindow.xaml.cs
private bool IsDisconnect = false; // flag to check whether session is disconnected or not.
private int counter;// to check the number of controls that are getting loaded or unloaded 

public MainWindow()
{
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionSwitch);
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UserControl), UserControl.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(UserControlLoaderUnloaderHandler));
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UserControl), UserControl.UnloadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(UserControlLoaderUnloaderHandler));
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Page), Page.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(PageLoaderUnLoaderHandler));
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Page), Page.UnloadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(PageLoaderUnLoaderHandler));
     //rest of the code
}

private void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Reason == SessionSwitchReason.) IsDisconnect = true;
        }

private void UserControlLoaderUnloaderHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var userControl = sender as UserControl;
            if (userControl != null && IsDisconnect)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                if (e.RoutedEvent == FrameworkElement.UnloadedEvent) counter++;
                if (e.RoutedEvent == FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent) counter--;
            }
            if (IsDisconnect && counter == 0) IsDisconnect = false;
        }

        private void PageLoaderUnLoaderHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var page = sender as Page;
            if (page != null && IsDisconnect)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                if (e.RoutedEvent == FrameworkElement.UnloadedEvent) counter++;
                if (e.RoutedEvent == FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent) counter--;
            }
            if (IsDisconnect && counter == 0) IsDisconnect = false;
        }

When RemoteDisconnect is the session switch cause, the SystemEvents_SessionSwitch method sets the IsDisconnect flag to true.
and in the UserControlLoaderUnloaderHandler and PageLoaderUnLoaderHandler methods, whenever a user control (UC) or page is unloaded, the same number of them will eventually need to be loaded again after a remote disconnect. To prevent the Loaded method in the UCs or Pages from being called, we set e.Handled = true;
By increasing a counter when UCs and pages are unloaded and decreasing it when they are loaded, we are able to keep track of how many UCs and pages are being loaded and unloaded. We use the condition (IsDisconnect && counter==0) to set the IsDisconnect flag to false after all of the UCs and pages have been loaded back, or when the counter hits zero.
So far, this solution has been effective. You can modify it by changing  the controls and making necessary adjustments accordingly.

In general, adding controls to the visual tree from code-behind usually leads to issues or unnecessarily complex code. It's rarely a solution
In your case if you want a UserControl to provide static content across all its instances and dynamic content you should override the default ControlTemplate.
The ControlTemplate contains the static content (it can bind to properties of the UserControl of course). But the client of the UserControl can't modify it (without overriding the ControlTemplate). The client adds his content as usual by setting the UserControl.Content property.
SectionsUserControl.xaml
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:PrintableContentHost">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- Header row -->
          <RowDefinition /> <!-- Content row -->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
          <TextBlock Text="I'm header content" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>

Now you can use the SectionsUserControl in multiple pages where the header content remains the same and only the actual page content changes.
To provide the dynamic content you can:
Example 1): define a DataTemplate and assign a data model to the UserControl.Content (e.g. a view model class in an MVVM context) or
Example 2): set the UserControl.Content property inline
Usage Example 1
PageModel.cs
class PageModel : INotifyPropertyChnaged
{
  public string PageText => "This is individual page content that is displayed below the header";
}

App.xaml
<ResourceDictionary>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="PageContentTemplate" 
                DataType="{x:Type PageModel}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PageText}" />
  </DataTemplate>
<ResourceDictionary>

MainWindow.xaml
<Window>

  <!-- 
    The ContentTemplate property is explicitly set in this example to 
    highlight the concept. 
    If the DataTemplate is implicit (keyless) then the template would be 
    automatically loaded by WPF. 
  -->
  <SectionsUserControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PageContentTemplate}">
    <SectionsUserControl.Content> <!-- You can bind the PageModel to the SectionsUserControl.Content property -->
      <PageModel />
    </SectionsUserControl.Content>
  </SectionsUserControl>
</Window>

Usage Example 2
MainWindow.xaml
<Window>
  <SectionsUserControl>
    <SectionsUserControl.Content>
      <TextBlock Text="This is individual page content that is displayed below the header" />
    </SectionsUserControl.Content>
  </SectionsUserControl>
</Window>

